# Linq join collection on collection

Tags: c#, linq

The Series object contains a property called Skus and it is IEnumerable
If this sku is in the allowed list of skus then I need that series.

In my example below, I'm joining on s.SeriesId which is not correct.
I believe it needs to be the collection s.Skus
I only want to return a series that has the contained sku in the collection.

```
        IEnumerable<Data.Models.Series> series = await _seriesRepository.GetSeriesAsync(Properties.Settings.Default.Channel, page, limit);
        string[] skusInSeries = series?.SelectMany(x => x.Skus).Distinct().ToArray();

        IEnumerable<string> itemNumbers = GetAllowedSkus(Customer, Shipto, EnvironmentCode, AcceptLanguage, skusInSeries, Warehouse);


        var selected = from s in series
                       join i in itemNumbers
                       on s.SeriesId equals i     //s.Skus  IEnumerable<string>
                       select s;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selected = from s in series
               where itemNumbers.Any(i => s.Skus.Contains(i))
               select s;
```

Or the other way:

```
var selected = from s in series
               where s.Skus.Any(sku => itemNumbers.Contains(sku))
               select s;
```

I am guessing there are more `Skus` than `itemNumbers` typically and the the first choice is better. It may also be better to change `itemNumbers` to a list that can be passed to the database:

```
var itemNumbers = GetAllowedSkus(Customer, Shipto, EnvironmentCode, AcceptLanguage, skusInSeries, Warehouse).ToList();
var selected = from s in series
               where itemNumbers.Any(i => s.Skus.Contains(i))
               select s;
```

If a SQL (or other) database isn't involved, you would convert `itemNumbers` to a `HashSet` for efficient lookup:

```
var itemNumbers = new HashSet<string>(GetAllowedSkus(Customer, Shipto, EnvironmentCode, AcceptLanguage, skusInSeries, Warehouse));

var selected = from s in series
               where s.Skus.Any(sku => itemNumbers.Contains(sku))
               select s;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That did it. I went with your solution involving the HashSet. No database is used. I will look up HashSet and learn more about it.